# SoapUI Groovy Script for date field to always use "last week"

Tags: soapui, api

I'm trying to use property as an input for API that requires a date. Since I'm remaking these tests every day, and will probably use them in future again, I want the value to be fluid. 
I encountered this tiny piece online for tomorrow

```
${=def lastWeek = new Date();lastWeek++;lastWeek.format("yy-MM-dd")}
```

But I have still yet to discover how to convince SoapUI NG Pro that I want a date one week from today.

Is there a possibility to make anything like this possible in SoapUI, and is my approach correct?

Comment: Can you try lastWeek - 7 rather than lastWeek++

Comment: today is `3 rd March`, one week from today will be `10th March`? Is that you want?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the parameter eventualyl should be? What should that date represent?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to add a week to today as mentioned below:

```
${= def nextWeek = new Date() + 7; nextWeek.format("yy-MM-dd")}
```

For example, there is an element `deliverDate`:

```
<deliverDate>${= def nextWeek = new Date() + 7; nextWeek.format("yy-MM-dd")}</deliverDate>
```

Comment: @Mortynaut, have you tried the above solution?

Answer (score 1):

I found it best to clear the date first to avoid conflicts

```
//Clear the date value in your variable
def current = new Date().clearTime()

//Set the date as 7 days ago
def lastWeek = (current - 7)

//Print out
lastWeek.each { println it }
```

Save that value as a property using a command like

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("yourProp", lastWeek)
```

Assuming the groovy script is run before that variable is used (or put into a tearup script) the date stored in that property will always be 1 week ago.

Comment: I was slightly unclear is you meant in the future or past, for a week in the future, simply change the value to +7